# Generar gráfico de área usando Highcharts y MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, highcharts

Estoy usando Highcharts y necesito generar la serie mediante `JSON` pero no logro obtener los resultados esperados.

Este es el código:

```
public JsonResult GetLinearJSONData()
{
     var pedido = (from cust in db.Pedidos
                  group cust by cust.FechaPedido into ped
                  select new
                  {
                      name = ped.Key,
                      data = ped.Count()
                  });
     return new JsonResult { Data = pedido, 
                             JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Pero necesitaría que se genere de esta manera, en donde debe agrupar por nombre de ciudad para el nombre y luego crear internamente otro arreglo en donde me guarde los totales de pedidos por mes.

Por ejemplo:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
            'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 1940,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USA',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
            1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
            27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
            26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
            24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
            22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
            10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
    }, {
        name: 'USSR/Russia',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
            4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
            15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
            33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
            35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
            21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
    }]
  });
});
```

Este es link del ejemplo: [BasicArea](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/)

Comment: que necesitas,  el grafico por mes ? devolver el valor de data por separado como un objeto? explicate mejor.

Comment: Como escribí en el post, necesito poder cargar la serie, de acuerdo akl modelo que pase, así es como lo recibe pero yo necesito pasarlo con datos de la base de datos por medio de JSON, independientemente de por mes o por año, supongamos que si lo necesito por mes.

Comment: La serie debe contener NAME: XXX y también DATA: [1,2,3,x]